# Can you identify Hong-Ou-Mandel (HOM) interference using the $E$-field operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The fastest way of showing the HOM interference effect is through the following procedure:

$|1, 1\rangle = a^\dagger b^\dagger|0,0\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(c^\dagger+d^\dagger) (c^\dagger-d^\dagger)|0,0\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(c^\dagger c^\dagger - d^\dagger d^\dagger) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|2, 0\rangle+|0, 2\rangle)$

But, in principle, I think I should be able to do this with the electric field operator, $\hat{E}$, but I am having some trouble reproducing the same results. Basically my goal is to take the classical E-field operator, then quantize it for different modes, and derive the HOM interference.

If I quantize the beam-splitter operation as follows:

[image]

Classically, if I send in $E_1$ and $E_2$, I get two outputs of the form: $E_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(E_1-E_2)$ and $E_4 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(E_1+E_2)$.

I expect that if I quantize these operators making $E\rightarrow\hat{E}$, I will get the E-field operators for my beam splitter: $\hat{E}_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{E}_1-\hat{E}_2)$ and $\hat{E}_4 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat{E}_1+\hat{E}_2)$.

In my first attempt, I was expecting that applying this E-field operator to my initial state would give me the expected anti-bunching. That is I was expecting to see:

$\hat{E}_4|1, 1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|2, 0\rangle+|0, 2\rangle \right)$

..but I don't get this. If I make $\hat{E}_1 \propto a+a^\dagger$ and $\hat{E}_2 \propto b+b^\dagger$ then $\hat{E}_4 = \frac{1}{2}(a+a^\dagger+b+b^\dagger)$. If I directly apply that state to $|1, 1\rangle$ then I get $\hat{E}_4 |1, 1\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|0, 1\rangle +|2, 1\rangle +|1, 0\rangle +|1, 2\rangle  )$.

So obviously I think this procedure doesn't work, but I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work.

So is there no way to actually construct what the electric field operator is, and use that $E$-field output operator to identify HOM interference? (I MUST plug in the unitary transform for the modes as done in the beginning?)

Comment: Shouldn’t you be applying your electric field operators to the vacuum rather than $\vert 1,1\rangle$?  Your E-fields contain both creation and destruction operators so applying this to $\vert 1,1\rangle$ will not yield a 2-photon state (as you’ve shown).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, hmmm...but the E-field operator is just some general operator and doesn't actually specify what my input is, right?  For example, you agree if I wanted to find the average E-field of some state $|\Psi\rangle$, I would do: $\langle\Psi|E|\Psi\rangle$, right? (As opposed to $\langle 0, 0|E|0, 0\rangle$)

Comment: right but methinks your input state is something like $\hat E_1\hat E_2\vert 0,0\rangle$.  Now you pass this through the interferometer.  I’m not sure that you can use an average value of electric field as detection is bucket-detectors and modelled as projectors.  Maybe I don’t quite understand your question…

Comment: BTW is there a sign error in your $\vert 20\rangle+\vert 02\rangle$ since you have $c^\dagger c^\dagger - d^\dagger d^\dagger$?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the field operator into a creation and an annihilation part
$$ \hat{E}=\hat{E}^{(-)}+\hat{E}^{(+)} . $$
Then you just use the creation part in the same way that you've used $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$. The result should then be the same.